# Is it a code smell for objects to contain information regarding the context in which they're used?

Tags: c#, class-design

Lets say I'm making a game with a bunch of levels, whereby as you progress through levels, new types of enemies are introduced. If a developer has an enemy and wants to get the level an enemy can be found in, the most intuitive way I can think of allowing them to do this would be to store a list levels on the enemy that they are contained within. This however I feel like is a problem, because now I've coupled my enemy and my level together. My enemy now knows about the context in which it used. My research says that these kinds of relationships are unhealthy for maintaining software, but it seems intuitive to use from a level above.

Here's a very basic implementation:

```
public class Level
{
    List<Enemy> typesOfEnemies;
    public Level(List<Enemy> typesOfEnemies)
    {
        this.typesOfEnemies = new List<Enemy>(typesOfEnemies);

        for (int i = 0; i < typesOfEnemies.Count; i++)
        {
            typesOfEnemies[i].AddLevelContainedWithin(this);
        }
    }
}

public class Enemy
{
    public List<Level> levelsContainedWithin = new List<Level>();
    public void AddLevelContainedWithin(Level level)
    {
        levelsContainedWithin.Add(level);
    }
}
```

So there's probably a few problems associated with this code. The most obvious one that sticks out to me is that I can add a level to an enemy without updating my Level's types of enemies which puts them out of sync. I could resolve this by creating another class that does the work, ensuring the Level and Enemy stay in-sync, but now I've added a layer of code complexity. The developer now has another class they have to know about to work with.

My question is, how do I make this maintainable and intuitive to for a developer to use?

Comment: I would say this question is more appropriate for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Why not have a single class that manages whcih levels go to which enemy? So you have a dependency to that managing-class instead from within your Level- and your Enemey-class. So in fact you end up with not having n levels per enemey, but just a single manager for all enemies.

Comment: It is preferred for dependencies to be one-way dependencies. Like between application layers, or between classes. Why do you think that your `Enemy` should know about `Level` ?

Comment: @RomanKalinchuk Sais whom? It´s absoluteley okay that a child knows its father, and a father knows its children.

Comment: @HimBromBeere says Uncle Bob)) Still, your solution looks fine

Comment: @HimBromBeere EDIT: The solution you suggested is good for removing the dependency, however, the enemy still contains the context in which is used. Whether this is a bad thing or not, I'm not entirely sure, hence why I'm asking. You're solution does solve some of the problems with the code I posted so thank u

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can introduce another class that does the coupling:

```
class LevelManager
{
    public List<Enemy> GetEnemies(Level l) { ... }
    public List<Level> GetLevels(Enemy e) { ... }
}
```

Now all your data-objects have to know is the `LevelManager`.

Actually it´s not even neccessary to have this dependcy in neither your `Enemy`- nor your `Level`-class. If a developer wants to know in which levels an enemy can spawn, he may use the `LevelManager` instead.

Comment: Are there any negative consequences to me Storing the Levelmanager in the Enemy class so I can wrap it and create simple methods like Enemy.GetLevels? Or is it better to just have the developer be accustomed to using the LevelManager to do such work?


In my mind, having Enemy.GetLevels is very intuitive and doesn't require the developer to know about the LevelManager, but yes it creates another dependency.

Comment: @SebastianKing I guess the cleanest way is to **not** have the dependency on your object-classes, as it´s nothing an `Enemy` should care for.